# Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 - Ethernet connection doesn't work

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, atheros

Today I launched Ubuntu 15.10 from bootable pendrive and tried to connect to the Internet using wired connection - it doesn't work (same on Ubuntu 14.04). Wireless connection is fine. I've tried a lot of solutions I found on the Internet, but none of them worked for me (probably because they were for older Ubuntu versions).

That's my Ethernet controller:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -vv | grep Atheros
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
```

Comment: The driver for your device, *alx* is included in Ubuntu 15.10 by default. Please load it: `sudo modprobe alx`, then check the message log for clues: `dmesg | grep -e 02:00 -e alx`Please post the result.

Comment: That's too long to post it in comment, so I used Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw/ahMFxGPk

Comment: May we see another paste? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n20`

Comment: To use the Internet by WiFi, I have to disconnect Ethernet cable, because without that it still doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/raw/NZfKAPpK

Comment: Does it start working if you do: `sudo dhclient enp2s0` Or else: `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: Both of them changed nothing. But the first one returned: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.